# Is Spring Integration Mail IMAP support OAuth2?

Tags: spring-boot, email, spring-integration, imap, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using Spring integration mail for imap idle events. I want to implement a IMAP gmail client using the token instead of using username and password.

Is Spring Integration Mail IMAP able to connect to gmail store with access token?

Here's the code I used

```
IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter("imaps://[username]:[password]@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox")
                    .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                            .put("mail.debug", "false")
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .shouldReconnectAutomatically(true)
                    .userFlag("testSIUserFlag")
                    .headerMapper(new DefaultMailHeaderMapper()))
            .handle((Message<?> message) -> {
                logger.info("message: " + message);
            })
            .get();
```

Comment: I think it doesn't. Any ideas how to do that with plain Java Mail API? So, we can adapt it into Spring Integration afterwards. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sounds like we just need to perform some REST request to get a token and together with some Java Mail properties set it into the URL instead of that `[password]` placeholder: https://kgiann78.github.io/java/gmail/2017/03/16/JavaMail-send-mail-at-Google-with-XOAUTH2.html

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); // required for Gmail
 props.put("mail.imap.sasl.enable", "true");
 props.put("mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
 props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
 props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
```

For this purpose it sounds like you should use dynamic flow registration, so you can perform token request first and then register that `Mail.imapIdleAdapter()` based on the result of the first request: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

Comment: Thanks for reply. The access token is retrieved successfully and set into url but I'm getting _javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)_.

Comment: Do you set those Java Mail properties? And I would say an URL should be like this: `imap://[username]:[accessToken]@imap.gmail.com/inbox`

Comment: Thanks, it's working now after I changed from imaps to imap for the URL.