# Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified? Spring Integration Imap adapter with Oauth2

Tags: spring-integration

I have tried below code.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imap://[emailId]:[accesstoken]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX")
                .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true).javaMailProperties(p -> p
                        .put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true")
                .put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true")
                .put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2")
                .put("mail.imaps.auth.login.disable", "true")
                .put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true")
                .put("mail.debug.auth", "true")
                ).shouldDeleteMessages(false).get(), 
                 e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> logMail(payload))
            .get();
    }
```

I have referred [Is Spring Integration Mail IMAP support OAuth2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508715/is-spring-integration-mail-imap-support-oauth2/61509594#61509594)

I get below exception

```
15:46:31.870 ERROR [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.doReceive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:74)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:407)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:376)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$3(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:323)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:320)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't show the whole stack trace. I believe there is some `cause by` for that `MailReceivingMessageSource.doReceive()`. Secondly it is not clear what is your `accesstoken` for this configuration since we can get it only at runtime when we call an OAuth REST endpoint for such a token. And only after that you can configure an `IntegraitonFlow` dynamically for already retrieved token. And finally there should be some DEBUG logs for Java Mail according your `"mail.debug.auth", "true"` config. Plus the mentioned SO question is marked as solved. So, you indeed do something what doesn't fit to the required model or is fully not related to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check gmail settings if you have enabled the allow of conection for less secure applications. You should put it off to connect to gmail from outside